# Dead-lettering dead-lettered messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, dead-letter

Here's what we have here:

- Topic Exchange `DLE`, which is intended to be a Dead-Letter Exchange
- Topic Exchange `E`, which is the "main" Exchange
- Several Queues (`EQ1`, ..., `EQn`) bound to `E` (and initialized with `x-dead-letter-exchange = DLE`), each with own Routing Key. These queues are the ones being consumed from.
- For each `EQn`, there's a `DLEQn` (initialized with `x-dead-letter-exchange = E` and `x-message-ttl = 5000`), bound to `DLE` with the same routing key as `EQn`. These queues are *not* being consumed from

What I want is the following: if a consumer cannot process a message from `EQn`, it Nacks the message with `requeue: false` and it gets to the `DLEQn` - that is, to an appropriate queue on the Dead-Letter Exchange. Now, I want this message to sit on the `DLEQn` for some time and then get routed back to the original queue `EQn` to be processed again.

Try as I might, I could not get the "redelivery to the original queue" working. I see that messages sit in the `DLEQn` with all the right headers and Routing Key intact, but after TTL expires they just vanish into thin air.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  We are currently doing this in production and it works great.  The code is too long to include here but I will show you the diagram I created that represents the process.  The basic idea is that the First DLX has a TTL, once that TTL expires the message goes into a 2nd queue to be re-sent back into the original.

[image]

Comment: How does it get resent to the original queue? Is it RabbitMQ that does the resending or is there a separate consumer on the retry queue?

Comment: A separate consumer picks up the message from "retry redirect queue" and looks at the rabbit headers.  The header of interest is "x-death", inside there it has the exchange and queue that the message came from.  We use this to send messages back to many different queues, that way we only need one "retry redirect queue".  Make sense?

Comment: @jhilden  Could you please tell how do you maintain count of the failed messages. Do you use some inbuilt functionality or you had maintain custom variable of count and you increment everytime it is retried

Comment: Custom variable, here is the code that checks that count:  https://gist.github.com/jayhilden/2078872a53c7df0fe45d661861ed2d45

Comment: @jhilden When you get x-death at "Retry Redirect Queue" wouldn't it be holding "Retry Holding Queue" name and not inbound queue - because that's where it came from?

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure it will have an x-death of *both*, so I take the first one, which is the original queue.

Comment: @jhilden sorry to comment on such an old answer(great answer by the way) but the 'x-death' key is one that you added to your headers for the message properties correct? I have read the docs here, https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/spec.html#pika.spec.BasicProperties , and headers appears to be none. Does that header have to be called x-death and if so do you recall where in the docs this would be?

Comment: @jhilden I see my folly now. It shows when you access properties.headers after it has already been dead lettered. of course! As far as sending back to the original queue goes, that would be just another basic_publish I assume.

Answer (score 5):

RabbitMQ detects message flow cycling (E -> DLE -> E  -> DLE ...) and silently drops messages:

From [DLX manual (Routing Dead-Lettered Messages section)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html):

> It is possible to form a cycle of dead-letter queues. For instance, this can happen when a queue dead-letters messages to the default exchange without specifiying a dead-letter routing key. Messages in such cycles (i.e. messages that reach the same queue twice) will be dropped **if the entire cycle is due to message expiry.**

Comment: I wonder if "25107 permit dead-letter cycles" in RabbitMQ 3.1 ( http://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.1.0.txt ) actually allows them.

Comment: I guess asking for clarification in RabbitMQ user group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) will bring some light on this question. I don't think that it 25107 is your case while you are using message expiry, which is the case to drop messages according to doc (i made bold that part)

Comment: Well, my cycle is decidedly _not_ entirely because of expiry. Nacking original message moves it from E to DLE, and only then does TTL comes into play. Nevertheless, thanks for taking time!

Answer (score 3):

That post is pretty old, but it took me days to find a solution for a similar problem, so I thought I should share my solution here.

We're receiving messages in TargetQueue (no TTL!!!, bound to TargetExchange) which may be nacked by the consumer. TargetQueue has a DLX defined (RetryExchange), which in turn has bound a corresponding queue (RetryQueue, with a TTL of 60 secs, TargetExchange defined as DLX).

So if the consumer nacks a message from TargetQueue, it gets queued up in the RetryQueue and because of the TTL, the message gets nacked again and requeued in the original TargetQueue. The clue was, that TargetQueue may not have a TTL defined, otherwise a message like this appears in the RabbitMQ log:

> Dead-letter queues cycle detected: [<<"TargetQueue">>,<<"RetryQueue">>,<<"TargetQueue">>]

So in the end the solution is pretty straight forward (and only needs one consumer). I got the final inspiration from https://medium.com/@igkuz/ruby-retry-scheduled-tasks-with-dead-letter-exchange-in-rabbitmq-9e38aa39089b