# How to handle stuck RabbitMQ Dynamic Shovel messages

Tags: rabbitmq, azure-eventhub, rabbitmq-shovel

We are currently using **RabbitMQ Dynamic Shovels** to forward messages to **Azure Event Hub**. Recently we setup a new Queue to be forwarded to Event Hub. Some messages in this Queue have a size of over **1MB** which is the limit for messages on Event Hub. Because of this limit the messages bounce back and are sent again a few times each second. This creates a lot of network traffic which can be an issue.

Is there any way to send messages that bounce back to a DLX (dead letter exchange) or to a different queue? We have looked for some Dynamic Shovel options but could not find any that would be of any use.

Comment: Generally, for cases when your payload is (or may be) larger than the allowable size, we recommend considering the [claim check pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check) where you store your payload in some other durable store (such as Blob storage) and then publish the event with a body that points to that resource.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JesseSquire! Will take a look if we can use this approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Jesse Squire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159548/jesse-squire). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> Generally, for cases when your payload is (or may be) larger than the allowable size, we recommend considering the [claim check pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check) where you store your payload in some other durable store (such as Blob storage) and then publish the event with a body that points to that resource.

You can refer to [Dead-lettering dead-lettered messages in RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631380/dead-lettering-dead-lettered-messages-in-rabbitmq).

You can also open an issue on GitHub: [rabbitmq-server](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues)